# A simple hangman game in Haskell

Tags: game, haskell, hangman

I just finished a course of functional programming in uni and continued to study Haskell because I found it very interesting! I made a simple hangman game and would like to hear any of your thoughts and ideas that may arise looking at the code! What, for example, could make it more dogmatic in a functional programming sense?

````hs
import Control.Monad
import Data.List (elemIndices, sort)

pictures = 9

main :: IO ()
main = do
  word <- getWord ""
  clearScreen
  hang word

hang :: String -> IO ()
hang word = hang' word [] [] pictures

hang' :: String -> [Char] -> [Char] -> Int -> IO ()
hang' word _ _ lives | lives == 0 = clearScreen >> putStrLn (renderHangman 0) >> putStrLn "You lost!" >> putStrLn ("The correct word was " ++ word ++ "\n")
hang' word rights _ lives | win rights word = clearScreen >> putStrLn (renderHangman lives) >> putStrLn "You won!" >> putStrLn ("The correct word was " ++ word ++ "\n")
hang' word rights wrongs lives = do
  clearScreen
  putStrLn $ renderHangman lives
  putStrLn $ renderWord rights word
  putStrLn $ renderLives lives
  putStrLn $ renderWrongs wrongs
  guess <- getGuess
  if guess `elem` (rights ++ wrongs)
    then hang' word rights wrongs lives
    else
      if correctGuess guess word
        then hang' word (guess : rights) wrongs lives
        else hang' word rights (guess : wrongs) (lives - 1)

win :: [Char] -> String -> Bool
win guesses = all (`elem` guesses)

clearScreen :: IO ()
clearScreen = replicateM_ 100 (putStrLn "")

correctGuess :: Char -> String -> Bool
correctGuess guess word = guess `elem` word

getGuess :: IO Char
getGuess = do
  putStrLn "Guess a letter!"
  getChar

getWord s = do
  clearScreen
  putStrLn "Give a secret word!"
  putStr ['*' | _ <- s]
  c <- getChar
  case c of
    '\n' -> return s
    char -> getWord (s ++ [char])

renderWord :: [Char] -> String -> String
renderWord guesses = foldr hide ""
  where
    hide = \x xs -> if x `elem` guesses then x : xs else '_' : xs

renderWrongs :: [Char] -> String
renderWrongs [] = ""
renderWrongs wrongs = "Wrong guesses: " ++ sort wrongs

renderHangman :: Int -> String
renderHangman = unlines . hangmanpics

renderLives :: Int -> String
renderLives lives = show lives ++ " guesses left!"

hangmanpics :: Int -> [String]
hangmanpics 9 = ["       ", "       ", "       ", "       ", "       ", "       ", "========="]
hangmanpics 8 = ["       ", "      |", "      |", "      |", "      |", "      |", "========="]
hangmanpics 7 = ["  +---+", "      |", "      |", "      |", "      |", "      |", "========="]
hangmanpics 6 = ["  +---+", "  |   |", "      |", "      |", "      |", "      |", "========="]
hangmanpics 5 = ["   +---+", "   |   |", "   O   |", "       |", "       |", "       |", " ========="]
hangmanpics 4 = ["   +---+", "   |   |", "   O   |", "   |   |", "       |", "       |", " ========="]
hangmanpics 3 = ["   +---+", "   |   |", "   O   |", "  /|   |", "       |", "       |", " ========="]
hangmanpics 2 = ["   +---+", "   |   |", "   O   |", "  /|\\  |", "       |", "       |", " ========="]
hangmanpics 1 = ["   +---+", "   |   |", "   O   |", "  /|\\  |", "  /    |", "       |", " ========="]
hangmanpics 0 = ["   +---+", "   |   |", "   O   |", "  /|\\  |", "  / \\  |", "       |", " ========="]
hangmanpics _ = ["   +---+", "   |   |", "   O   |", "  /|\\  |", "  / \\  |", "       |", " ========="]
```
````

Answer (score 4, accepted):

looks really good!

Here are some suggestions, in rough order of significance

1. The game essentially can be described by the three values `word`, `rights`, `wrongs`, and `lives` which you pass around between functions. For readability, I would suggest wrapping these up into a datatype:

   ```hs
   data GameState = GameState
     { word :: String
     , rights :: [Char]
     , wrongs :: [Char]
     , lives :: Int
     }
   ```
2. The end of `hang'` feels convoluted. By "end" I mean the code after `getGuess`. The semantic structure is this: "update" the "game state", and then restart `hang'`. But it's not easy to see that with the current code structure, since each branch is its own "independent" call to `hang'`.

   Storing state in its own `GameState` type, we can cleanly split the code into the parts (1) update the state; (2) call `hang'`. To cut to the chase, it looks like this:

   ```
   guess <- getGuess
   let state' =
         if guess `elem` (rights state ++ wrongs state)
         then state
         else if correctGuess guess state
         then state { rights = guess : rights state }
         else state { wrongs = guess : wrongs state, lives = lives state - 1 }

   hang' state'
   ```
3. `[Char]` is not quite an appropriate datatype for `rights` and `wrongs`. Using `[Char]` here suggests to me that you care about the order of the `Char`s in the list and how many times they show up, but in fact you do not. I would recommend [`Data.Set`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.6.5.1/docs/Data-Set.html) instead. (This will give you better performance, too!)
4. `getWord` can be implemented more simply as `clearScreen >> putStrLn "Give a secret word!" >> getLine`
5. `win` -- sleek implementation of this function!

   Unrelated, I would rename it. `win` sounds like an action, but really the function is a predicate. Perhaps `isWin`?
6. As a general rule of thumb, I would try to avoid unqualified imports like `import Control.Monad`. If you have more than one unqualified import, it can become difficult to know where a function or operator is being imported from.
7. `getWord` is missing its type signature, as is `pictures`. This is not a huge deal, but it's generally recommended to include type signatures on (at least) all top-level values.
8. In some places you chain `IO` actions with `>>` and in others you use `do` notation.

   These are actually the same thing; `thingOne >> thingTwo` and `do { thingOne; thingTwo; }` are the same code. (It's unclear to me if you know this already)

   Anyway, for readability I would suggest using `do` for longer chains and `>>` or `>>=` for shorter expressions. Concretely, rewrite the `clearScreen >> putStrLn ...` parts of `hang'` using `do`, and then rewrite `getGuess` as `putStrLn "Guess a letter!" >> getChar`.

Hope this helps :-) See the code with all changes made (except for using `Set`) [here](https://pastebin.com/raw/rundHreh)

Comment: Oh, one more: `renderWord` can be implemented as ``renderWord' guesses = foldMap (\c -> if c `elem` guesses then [c] else "_")``

Comment: This answer was definitely over the top. I agree with every bullet and can't thank you enough for seeing exactly what I was trying to do. I'll go through them one by one right away. Very kind of you to also throw in praise where you did, haha! Marking as solved.

Comment: @OlaBandola Good luck! I've included a reference implementation at the end of my answer, if it's helpful